# 404 Request Resource not found

Tags: spring, rest, http

I am using Spring Framework with restful web services, and I am trying to create an API with restful service and use a get method. I have created a method and I'm trying to have it return a string, but instead I get a 404 error - requested resources not found. Please see my code below:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class AreaController {

    public RestResponse find(@PathVariable String name, ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("movie", name);
        return "list";
    }
}
```

I am using: localhosr:8080/MyProject/wangdu

Comment: Shouldn't the localhost URL be /test ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs because you forgot to add 
`@RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)`
 before your find method:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class AreaController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public RestResponse find(@PathVariable String name, ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("movie", name);
        return "list";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure about this:

1. The value that the `find` method is returning is a String with the value `"list"` and the find method declaration is waiting for a `RestResponse` object

For example if I have a `RestResponse` object like this:

```
public class RestResponse {

    private String value;
    public RestResponse(String value){
        this.value=value;
    }

    public String getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Then try to return the value in this way:

```
public RestResponse find(@PathVariable String name, ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("movie", name);
    return new RestResponse("list");
}
```

2. Verify that the method has `@RequestMapping` annotation with the value that your expect from the url

   `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{name}")`
3. By default the proper way to call the rest resource is by the `@RequestMapping` value that you set at the `@RestController` level (`@RequestMapping("/test")`), in this case could be: `http://localhost:8080/test/myValue`

If you need to use a different context path then you can change it on the `application.properties` (for spring boot)

```
server.contextPath=/MyProject/wangdu
```

In that case you can call the api like this:

`http://localhost:8080/MyProject/wangdu/test/myValue`

Here is the complete code for this alternative:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class AreaController {


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{name}")
    public RestResponse find(@PathVariable String name, ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("movie", name);
        return new RestResponse("list");
    }
```